# Cannot cast from <Type> to Result by using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using Gson library to convert my JSON array of Objects to String.
But i am getting this error of **Cannot cast from DataIntent to Result**!!

DataIntent is the name of POJO class.

data.json

```
`{
 "dataIntents": [
   {
     "intent": "muster.policy.daily",
     "expr": "Am I supposed to register my attendance daily?"
   },
   {
     "intent": "leave.probation",
     "expr": "An employee is eligible for how many leaves ??"
   }
  ]
}`
```

POJO classes :

```
 public class DataIntent {

 private String intent;
 private String expr;

 //getters and setters

 }'
```

Example class

```
 public class Example {

 private List<DataIntent> dataIntents = null;

 public List<DataIntent> getDataIntents() {
    return dataIntents;
 }

 public void setDataIntents(List<DataIntent> dataIntents) {
    this.dataIntents = dataIntents;
 }

 }
```

Main class :

```
   public class JSONMain {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.json"));
        org.junit.runner.Result result = (org.junit.runner.Result) 
        gson.fromJson(br, DataIntent.class);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I dont know what i am doing wrong? As i am new to programming.
I have seen this over a video on youtube [(This link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y96VcLgOJqA)

I am getting problem on

```
org.junit.runner.Result result = (org.junit.runner.Result)gson.fromJson(br, DataIntent.class);
```

Is it the right Result i am using?? or else what is the other solutions so i can parse my JSONArray of objects to get key : value of 'expr'
Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gson.fromJson` deserialize the json string into an object of the class you provided as parameter, `DataIntent.class` in your case.
In the video you linked, `Result` is the class he's going to deserialize json string to.
In fact the statement is:

```
Result result = gson.fromJson(br, Result.class)
```

There's no cast needed, you just have to define the variable you want to instance with the result of the desarialization of the same type you're passing as parameter to fromJson method:

```
DataIntent di = gson.fromJson(br, DataIntent.class);
```

**Edit** based on your comment:
You should deserialize to your Example class:

```
Example example = gson.fromJson(br, Example.class);
```

and then loop through the list of DataIntent of the Example class:

```
for(DataIntent di : example.getDataIntents())
```

Comment: Heyy @DavisMolinari thankyou for your suggestion, as of now the Error has gone, but while i am adding a 'if' loop (as which is in video) i cannot do that.. as i want to iterate through and get all values of expr

Comment: @shubham You should pay attention of what he's doing in the video and reproduce it correctly: he has Result class that has a List of Todo objects. He deserialize the Result and loop through its list of Todo objects. You have Example class that is its Result and your DataIntent is its Todo. So you have to deserialize to Example and then loop through the list of DataIntent

Comment: @DavisMolani Thankyou so much  for your kind help :) it worked